# What does it mean to show a function acts as a permutation?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

I have been asked to show that the function $f:\Omega \to \Omega$,
$$f[x,y,z]=[x^2 +yz,y^2 ,z^2]$$ acts as a permutation on $\Omega$, the set of a one-dimensional subspaces of $V=\mathbb{F}_4^3$ (3d vector space from the field of four elements), where $[x,y,z]$ is the subspace spanned by $(x,y,z)$.

E: It is not asking to prove that $f[f[x,y,z]]=[x,y,z]$, as this is asked later.

Comment: Are $x,y,z$ specific elements? Or is this like an evaluation map over polynomial rings?

Comment: $x,y,z \in \mathbb{F_4}$ by definition, but this is just the general field with four elements.

Comment: Oh ok, so you've a map hopefully from $\Omega\to \Omega$, whereby you send the $1d$ space $\langle(x,y,z)\rangle\mapsto \langle(x^2+yz,y^2,z^2)\rangle$

Comment: Yup that's correct

Comment: I've just googled "Bijective Permutation" and found "A bijective function from a set to itself is also called a permutation." from wikipedia so yeah I have to show it's bijective. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For every $D\in\Omega$, let us denote by $f\left<D\right>$ the set $\{f(v);v\in D\}$.

IMHO, the question asks to prove that :

- $\forall D\in\Omega,\,f\left< D\right>\in\Omega$
- the map $\Omega\to\Omega,D\mapsto f\left<D\right>$ is bijective

Comment: But the function is defined to be acting on $\Omega$ i.e. $f:\Omega \to \Omega$. Surely I'd just be proving $f[x,y,z]=[x,y,z]$